# How do I seal and make this window in brick casement look better?

Tags: brick, window-frame

I have a window from my kitchen that goes through a brick veneer wall. The wall shifted at some point in time years ago, pulling slightly away from the house. As a result, there is a much larger gap than normal at the sides and top.

I have previously temporarily covered the largest gaps with adhesive window flashing (which is why part of the white plastic around the window is discolored). Then I put some expanding foam in the gap, cut it square, and caulked over it - learning a hard lesson about caulking brick in the process (e.g. I know my caulking job looks like crap on the left and right sides).

Now I am thinking about install brick moulding around the edges. The trouble with that is that the top brown board does not quite line up with the window (see photo detailing - the bottom of that board sticks out maybe 1/2" further than the window). So if I just do brick moulding around the whole thing, there will be a not-small gap between the moulding and the window. [This is the moulding I bought](https://www.lowes.com/pd/EverTrue-2-in-x-10-ft-Interior-Wood-Brick-Actual-2-in-x-10-ft/1000445521) which is probably too wide in any event.

But! I am not attached to any specific method. I just want to seal this window (and top board) up, and have it look reasonably decent.

What is the right solution for a novice here? If it weren't for that top board, I would just nail some moulding into the brick, caulk everything up and call it a day.

Photos detailing the problem window (the non-painted lumber there is a 1x2 that I temporarily stuck in the gap after removing a mess of molding and caulk):
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Some PVC "lumber" and caulk above the window?